# Quiero hacer un FadeIn a dos elementos usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero hacer es un `FadeIn` con `jQuery` pero no lo consigo:

Mi JS:

```
function fadein() {

     $("#result").fadeIn(1000);
     $("#svgresult").fadeIn(1000);

    }
```

```html
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="fadein();">Calculate</button>

<svg id="svgresult" style="display: none; position:fixed; bottom: 0px; height: 220px; background:#0092ED; width: 100%;"></svg>
<h1 id="result" style="display: none">Result</h1>
```

Y lo que quiero hacer, es que cuando presionas "Calculate" hacer un FadeIn del texto "Result" y su fondo.

**Actualización 12 Setiembre 2016**

```js
 <script>
 
 
 $('#calculate').click(function() {
  $('#svgresult, #result').fadeIn();
});
 
   function calculate() {
  
  
   //Mostrar el texto resultado más el fondo del texto
   //document.getElementById("result").style.visibility = "visible";
   //document.getElementById("svgresult").style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById("operatortext").style.visibility = "hidden";
 
   //Varibles de la operación
   var v1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
   var o = document.getElementById("operator").value;
   var v2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;
 
 
   //Advierte de que el operando introducido no es válido
   if (o =="") alert("Please insert an operator!");
 
   //Si no se ha introducido ningún valor, sustituirlo por 0
   if (v1 =="") v1 = document.getElementById("value1").value = "0";
   if (v2 =="") v2 = document.getElementById("value2").value = "0";

   //Generar un número aleatorio
   if (o =="?" || o =="¿")  var H = Math.random();
        var X = ((H * 100) / 4);
                          var text = "" + X + "";
                          document.forms.form1.area.value = text
   
   //Suma
   if (o =="+") var resultsum = Number(v1) + Number(v2);
   if (o =="+") var text = ("" + resultsum + "");
                      document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
 
   //Resta
   if (o =="-") var resultrest = Number(v1) - Number(v2);
   if (o =="-") var text = ("" + resultrest + "");
             document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
     
   //Multiplicación
   if (o =="*" || o =="·" || o =="x" || o =="X") var resultmult = Number(v1) * Number(v2);
   if (o =="*" || o =="·" || o =="x" || o =="X") var text = ("" + resultmult + "");
                                                       document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
     
   //División
   if (o =="/" || o ==":") var resultdiv = Number(v1) / Number(v2);
   if (o =="/" || o ==":") var text = ("" + resultdiv + "");
                                 document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
     
   //Potencia
   if (o =="^" || o =="**" || o =="^^") var resultpower = Math.pow(v1, v2);
   if (o =="^" || o =="**" || o =="^^") var text = ("" + resultpower + "");
                                                 document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
     
   //Si el resultado no es numérico mostrar un determinado mensaje    
   if (isNaN(text)) var text = "Unable to calculate the result!";
                 document.forms.form1.area.value = text;
   
   //Si el resultado no es numérico, ocultar el texto resultado y la caja de fondo
   //if (isNaN(text)) document.getElementById("result").style.visibility = "hidden";
   //if (isNaN(text)) document.getElementById("svgresult").style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
 
 
  
  function calc() {
  
   window.location = "http://www.bananatestlol.weebly.com";
   
 }
 
 
     function tips() {
  
   window.location = "http://www.bananatestlol.weebly.com/tips.html";
   
 }
  

</script>
```

```css
#value1 {

 
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 300%;
 width: 250px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 color: #0092ED;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 35%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 
}



#value1:hover {

 
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 300%;
 width: 280px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 color: #0092ED;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 35%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: -90px;
 
}



#value1:focus {

 background: #0072B8;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 0px solid #0072B8;
 width: 280px;
 margin-left: -90px;
 font-weight: bold;

}



#operatortext {

 color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 57%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);


}


#operator {

 font-size: 300%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666666;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}


#operator:hover {

 font-size: 300%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 60px;
 border: 0px solid white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666666;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
}



#operator:focus {

 border: 0px solid #666666;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #999999;
 width: 60px;

}


#value2 {

 font-size: 300%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 border: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 color: #0092ED;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 65%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: 60px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}


#value2:hover {

 font-size: 300%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 280px;
 border: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-radius: 15px;
 outline: none;
 color: #0092ED;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffffff;
 left: 65%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: 90px;
}



#value2:focus {

 background: #0072B8;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: 0px solid #0072B8;
 width: 280px;
 margin-left: 90px;
 font-weight: bold;

}




h1 {

 font-size: 250%;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 


}




#calculate {



 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid #ffffff;
 font-size: 250%;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #666666;
 border-radius: 25px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 30%;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 outline: none;
 padding: 15px 30px;

}

#calculate:hover {

 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: transparent;
 border-radius: 25px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 top: 30%;
 opacity: 0.5;
 outline: none;
 

}


textarea {

 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 
 height: 150px;
 min-height: 150px;
 max-height: 150px;
 
 border: 0px solid #ffffff;
 background: #ffffff;
 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 425%;
 color: #0092ED;
 outline: none;
 
 transition: all 0.3s;

}




textarea:hover {

 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 
 height: 220px;
 min-height: 220px;
 max-height: 220px;
 
 border: 0px solid #0092ED;
 background: #0092ED;
 
 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 500%;
 color: #ffffff;
 outline: none;

}



#result {
 
 position: fixed;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 140px;
 color: #ffffff;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}


#calculator {
 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #ffffff;
 border-left: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #F3003D;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #F3003D;
 font-size: 150%;
 outline: none;
 transition: all 0.3s;

}


#calculator:hover {
 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #F3003D;
 border-left: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #F3003D;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 250%;
 font-weight: bold;
 outline: none;

}



#calculator:focus {
 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #F3003D;
 border-left: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #F3003D;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 250%;
 font-weight: bold;
 outline: none;

}


#tips {

 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #ffffff;
 border-left: 0px solid #10E152;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #10E152;
 font-size: 150%;
 outline: none;
 transition: all 0.3s;

}

#tips:hover {

 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #10E152;
 border-left: 0px solid #10E152;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 250%;
 font-weight: bold;
 outline: none;

}


#tips:focus {

 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 50%;
 background: #10E152;
 border-left: 0px solid #10E152;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-right: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-top: 0px solid #ffffff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 250%;
 font-weight: bold;
 outline: none;

}








.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  top: 120px;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title {

  color: #ffffff;
  height: 176px;
  background: url("https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/8/8/5/8/88581596/custom_themes/359885798850792406/files/images/Imagen79.jpg") center;
}
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu {
  color: #ffffff;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,500,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.teal-red.min.css" />
<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background: url(https://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/8/8/5/8/88581596/custom_themes/359885798850792406/files/images/Imagen791.jpg) 15% 30%;"  class='  wsite-theme-light'>
<!-- Valor de la operación 1 -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="center">
    <input class="center" type="number" id="value1">
    <label id="labelvalue1" class="mdl-textfield__label" for="value1"></label>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Operador -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="center">
    <input class="center" type="text"  id="operator" maxlength="2">
    <label id ="labeloperator" class="mdl-textfield__label" for="operator"></label>
  </div>
</form>
<h2 id="operatortext" onclick="tips()">Operator</h2>


<!-- Valor de la operación 2 -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="center">
    <input class="center" type="number" id="value2">
    <label id="labelvalue2" class="mdl-textfield__label" for="value2"></label>
  </div>
</form>


<!-- Botón calcular --> 
<button id="calculate" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

<!-- Texto resultado más el fondo del texto -->
<svg id="svgresult" style="display: none; position:fixed; bottom: 0px; height: 220px; background:#0092ED; width: 100%;"></svg>
<h1 id="result" style="display: none">Result</h1>


<!-- Resultado -->
<form name="form1">
 <textarea readonly="readonly" name="area" ?echo $descripcion;?>The result will be showed here</textarea>
</form>


<!-- Menú -->
<svg id="menubackbox" style="position:fixed; background: #ffffff; opacity: 1; width: 100%; height: 80px; top: 0%; "></svg>
<button id="calculator" onclick="setTimeout(calc, 100)">Calculator</button>
<button id="tips" onclick="setTimeout(tips, 100)">Info</button>  


<!--
class='wsite-theme-light'>
<div style='display:none'>{title}</div>
<div style='display:none'>{menu}</div>
<div style='display:none'>{content}</div>
<div style='padding: 20px; width:100%; text-align:center;'>{footer}</div>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Este es el código entero, espero que puedas ayudarme., ¡gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) en el botón y aplicando [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) en los dos elementos en mención:

```js
$('#calculate').click(function() {
  $('#svgresult, #result').fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>

<svg id="svgresult" style="display: none; position:fixed; bottom: 0px; height: 220px; background:#0092ED; width: 100%;"></svg>
<h1 id="result" style="display: none">Result</h1>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta podrías considerar aceptarla, haciendo clic en la "marca de chequeo" a la izquieda de la misma.

Comment: Añado el jQuery que me has dado dentro de la funcion o donde lo pongo?

Comment: Reemplaza el código JavaScript que tenías por el que proporcioné.

Comment: No me funciona :(

Comment: Es que en realidad tengo más de una función en el programa que se encarga de hacer los cálculos, y luego pongo fuera de esa el script que me has dado pero no me funciona :( porque l oque quiero hacer es que el boton ejecute la funcion del calculo y que tambien haga la transicion

Comment: En ese orden de ideas tienes que adaptar tu código para que funcione con lo que te puse, no conozco tu código sino únicamente lo que pusiste acá, y como te das cuenta, **funciona**. Asumo que ya incluiste jQuery?

Comment: Si lo añadí, pero sigue sin funcionarme, si quieres te paso el código completo